# Django template how to re-use a template html file twice

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have three files:

1. base.html
2. results.html extends base.html
3. results_only.html (standalone)

`results_only.html` is only called with ajax and returned `<tr>` fields only. Those `<tr>` lines are duplicated in `results.html` currently, I'd rather have them not be duplicated.

How can I "import" `results_only.html` `results.html`... Something like:

File `results.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header%}...{% endblock%}
{% block content}
<div>Results Are:</div>
<table>
   <tbody>
      {% import "results_only.html" %}
   </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

I'd rather not duplicate the the contents of `results_only.html` in two places.

Hope that my question is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include

```
{% include "results_only.html" %}
```

I think everything is clear :)

Comment: Thank you, i'd hate to say I tried searching but sometimes you just can't come up with the correct thing to search. In this case "include", I searched for "block within a block" "nested blocks" etc. 

Humans are still smarter at guessing what I want :)